# How do I go from Planck units to string units?

Tags: string-theory

I am not sure exactly what "string units" are. I know that $\alpha' = l_{string}^2 = \frac{1}{M_{string}^2}.$ But these are not units per see, I still need values for $l_{string}$  and $M_{string}$ that could be in whatever units?

My question is, how do I go between string units and Planck units? Alos, what is the unit of $g_s$ the string coupling constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The closed-string string coupling constant $g_s$ in both bosonic and superstring theory is the vacuum expectation value of $e^\Phi$, where $\Phi$ is the dilaton field. It is dimensionless: indeed, all dimensionless parameters in string theory arise as VEV's of scalar fields.
- In the bosonic case, the 26D Planck length $\ell_p$ is set via $\ell_p^{24}=\ell_s^{24}g_s^2$. This is seen via the low-energy bosonic effective action. The 26D Planck mass is related as $M_p=\ell_p^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you @Nihar! I did not know that the dilation field was dimensionless. Do you know how this would differ in a SUSY theory? Please let me know if you have some good sources, I don't really find anything useful.

Comment: @JohnGreger sorry, should have been clearer there: it's the same relation in superstring theory. As for sources, I think this is there in David Tong's lecture notes online.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! Answer accepted :)